# Floating point difficulties in R and in particular in Hmisc's minor.tick

Tags: r, floating-point, numeric

When I call

```
library(Hmisc)
plot(...)
minor.tick(...)
```

occasionally I'll run into the following error:

```
Error in seq.default(low.minor, hi.minor, by = distance.between.minor) : 
  'to' cannot be NA, NaN or infinite
In addition: Warning message:
In max(possible.minors[possible.minors <= range[2]]) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

In `minor.tick` there are the following lines:

```
range <- par("usr")[if (w == "x") 1:2 else 3:4]
tick.pos <- if (w == "x") par("xaxp") else par("yaxp")
...
possible.minors <- tick.pos[2] + (0:100) * distance.between.minor
hi.minor <- max(possible.minors[possible.minors <= range[2]])
```

when I print out the values of `possible.minors` and `range[2]`, I see, for example,

`> possible.minors
  [1] 1.20 1.24 1.28 1.32 1.36 1.40 1.44 1.48 1.52 1.56 1.60 1.64 1.68 1.72 1.76
 [16] 1.80 1.84 1.88 1.92 1.96 2.00 2.04 2.08 2.12 2.16 2.20 2.24 2.28 2.32 2.36
 [31] 2.40 2.44 2.48 2.52 2.56 2.60 2.64 2.68 2.72 2.76 2.80 2.84 2.88 2.92 2.96
 [46] 3.00 3.04 3.08 3.12 3.16 3.20 3.24 3.28 3.32 3.36 3.40 3.44 3.48 3.52 3.56
 [61] 3.60 3.64 3.68 3.72 3.76 3.80 3.84 3.88 3.92 3.96 4.00 4.04 4.08 4.12 4.16
 [76] 4.20 4.24 4.28 4.32 4.36 4.40 4.44 4.48 4.52 4.56 4.60 4.64 4.68 4.72 4.76
 [91] 4.80 4.84 4.88 4.92 4.96 5.00 5.04 5.08 5.12 5.16 5.20`

`> range[2]
[1] 1.2`

which ultimately gives us

```
> possible.minors[1]
[1] 1.2
> range[2]
[1] 1.2
> possible.minors[1] <= range[2]
[1] FALSE
```

so 1.2 is not less than or equal to 1.2. Ok, clearly some floating point nonsense going on here. How can I resolve this?

**Addendum:**

When I print more digits, I find

```
> print(possible.minors[1], digits=20)
[1] 1.2000000000000001776
> print(range[2], digits=20)
[1] 1.1999999999999999556
```

it seems that the author of this package anticipated this, because the next line checks whether the result is NA, and if so, assigns a value. Maybe this worked in previous versions of R, but it seems now to cause the package to crash. In any case, I think the correct way is to check if there are any values such that the inequality holds, and if so pick the max, and if not then do the other thing. Now, I can implement this change on my own machine, but how do I give it to the fellow Hmisc users of the world?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have posted this as an [issue on the Hmisc github](https://github.com/harrelfe/Hmisc/issues/28).

I think one quick solution is to change the lines

```
if (is.na(low.minor))
```

and

```
if (is.na(hi.minor))
```

to

```
if (is.na(low.minor) || is.infinite(low.minor))
```

and

```
if (is.na(hi.minor) || is.infinite(hi.minor))
```

but a better solution is to first check whether

```
any(possible.minors >= range[1])
```

and

```
any(possible.minors <= range[2])
```

before doing any indexing so that warning messages are avoided.

Comment: Suggested fixes have been incorporated on Github and will be in the next release or may be obtained using getRs('minor.tick.s', grepo='Hmisc', dir='R', put='source')